# How to flash a ZIP file with Odin?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, odin

I can't boot my Galaxy Tab 8.9 / P7300 anymore, but Odin still detects a USB connection. So I'm trying to flash a new ROM onto it using Odin. However all I can find on the web are ZIP archives containing boot.img, META-INF etc, while Odin apparently needs .tar or .tar.md5 files.

Can I convert one into the other, or is my idea completely wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.zip` files are generally flashable from recovery, Odin's `.tar`s are indeed a completely different format.  If flashing a kernel you can convert them relatively easily (thought I won't get into it here) but it won't work for a whole ROM.  You'll need to find an Odin package.  XDA is your best bet, but see also: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465)

Comment: (to OP) If you want to have a custom Rom running Jelly bean you can look over here: [CWM recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1312218), Cyanogenmod 10 Jelly Bean nightly builds are [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1777398)

Comment: If you don't want to get into it here, maybe a short link would be of help for many people. See what ranking this page has in search engines.
I guess a tool like 7zip is well capable of unzipping and making a tar of it. Unfortunately, i have no clue of how the md5 sum can be calculated and packaged with 7zip.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone reading this that is also late to the discussion: If you found the Zipped Rom in question on XDA, it was probably originally a tar file that someone renamed zip in order to use a file hosting website with a restriction against tar files. (As this simple rename just worked for me.)

Comment: You should definitely verify the file type and structure if you think it's misnamed.  Assuming otherwise is a good way to brick your phone.